# How to replace href using javascript regex in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, regex, cross-browser

I try to change some links on a webpage using the following code for jQuery on Rails

```
$(function () {
  $('#lesson a').live('click', function () {
    $.getScript(this.href.replace(/^(http...[^\/]+)?\/+(.*)$/,'/ajax/\\$2'));
    return false;
  });
})
```

This trick works for Chrome and Safari, but fails (nothing happens on click) for Firefox and Opera. What can be wrong with the code?

EDIT1:

The webpage contains:

```
<div id="lesson">
  <a href="/subj1">Subject 1</a>
  ...
</div>
```

On click, a browser (i.e. Firefox and Opera) should make an ajax-request of `/ajax/subj1`.

Comment: Can you include source of an example HTML page as well?

Comment: @orangepips, Just did it. Please, see the updated question.

Comment: In what way does it fail? What errors do you receive?

Comment: instead of returning false you should `function(e) { e.preventDefault(); /* your code */}`

Comment: @lonesomeday, nothing happens after click

Comment: @Jimmy, following you suggestion the links work (in Firefox) but they are not replaced and lead to '/subj1' instead of `/ajax/subj1`

Comment: I know--it is better to prevent default behavior instead of halting execution and returning false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You replace the string with `'/ajax/\\$2'`.
You have an extra backslash - if you expect the result `/ajax/subj1`, use `'/ajax/$2'`.

Comment: thanks! I've misread how one refers a regex part in javascript. It is interesting that it worked for some browsers.

Comment: @Andrei - no problem! Sometimes you write something, and then blinded by it - even though it's right in your face `:)`. Some browsers are very forgiving - they correct urls and even html, assuming the user mistyped it. For example, http:/google.com will work in most browsers, even though it isn't a valid url. IE auto corrects `\ ` to `/` (or at least did 7 years ago - hadn't checked since), and probably collapses `//` to `/`, giving a correct result.